# Термин "cmdlet" не распознается как имя командлета

Tags: windows-10, powershell, jenkins

С сервера дженкинс при помощи плагина PowerShell запускается команда (к примеру wuauclt /reportnow) на виртуальной машине виндовс 10, которая является слейвом дженкинс. В результате джоба билдится с ошибками:

```
Started by user Maksim
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on win1709_v3 in workspace C:\workspace\TestConnection
[TestConnection] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\waters\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins6652879307998581316.ps1'"
wuauclt : The term 'wuauclt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\waters\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins6652879307998581316.ps1:3 char:1
+ wuauclt /reportnow
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (wuauclt:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Finished: SUCCESS
```

Изначально сервис Jenkins client работал от юзера system, позже я выставил запуск сервиса от своей учетной записи - ошибка осталась. Вручную и в PowerShell и в cmd эта команда работает корректно. Такая ошибка происходит с большинством запущенных из дженкинса командлетов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как устранить эту ошибку и корректно запустить команду.

Comment: так а там этот плагин установлен?

Comment: @VTT, да, установлен. еще забыл сказать что пробовал явно указывать путь к  командлетам - не сработало